# How to take input from a Select box to a Text box with for loop

Tags: javascript

I was trying to write a code that would enable me display the value of a select box in a text box and it was getting kind of bulky so I decided to try looping the code to enable for easy but my java script seems not to be working

**HTML Code**

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" id="text1" style="width: 40px;height: 25px;" name="">
<select id="first" onclick="input1()">
                <option value="10">A1</option>
                <option value="9">B2</option>
                <option value="8">B3</option>
                <option value="7">C4</option>
                <option value="6">C5</option>
                <option value="5">C6</option>
            </select>
```

**Java Script Code**

```
    var Score = ["A1" , "B2", "B3'', "C4'' ,"C5'', "C6''];
    for(i = 10 ; i>4 ; i--) `{
        for(j=0 ; j<Score.length ; j++) {
            If(first.Value==I ) {
                Document.getElementById('Text1').value = Score[j] ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello! I see you have extra ' and " on your code. Also, where does the word `first` come from, it's not defined.

Comment: @JoseBarranco  i defined it in the HTML file sorry I didnt post it but that Is the id for my select button 1 for all options

Comment: I agree with @David Thomas what are you trying to achieve? Like, using a decrement operator (i--), I'm just not getting what you want to do specifically.

Comment: I will add my html code so it would be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit complicated what you're doing.

You have to double check your syntax

- `Document => document`
- `If => if`
- `first.Value==I`, `first` does not exist neither does `I`
- `var Score = ["A1" , "B2", "B3'', "C4'' ,"C5'', "C6'']; => var Score = ["A1" , "B2", "B3", "C4" ,"C5", "C6"];`

This can be achieved without a single loop. Add an event listener to your select and if the value changes update the textbox.

```js
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener("change", e => {
  const select = e.target;
  document.getElementById('text1').value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text ;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" style="width: 40px;height: 25px;" name="">

<select id="first">
    <option value="10">A1</option>
    <option value="9">B2</option>
    <option value="8">B3</option>
    <option value="7">C4</option>
    <option value="6">C5</option>
    <option value="5">C6</option>
</select>
```

Maybe i got you completely, if so tell me then I will edit my question or delete it.

Comment: Thank you very much I tried this the only problem was the value was what showed in the text box I wanted the text A1 b2 and the rest to show in the text instead of the value